# Signal handler on mysql connection break

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, mysql-5, mysqld

I want to know if there is any signal that I can catch by which I can know that my mysql connection with the server has broken in c programming? I know I can check at query time whether my connection is active or not. But I just want to know if there is any signal I can catch so that I will not have to go though any connection checking process.

Comment: No, there is not. The API has a `ping`-method, but you will have to call it from your side, the server will not tell you on its own if it has gone down or lost connection to you. If your framework doesn't do it already (e.g. do keep your connection alive), you can use e.g. a timer event to regularly ping it.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23861221/handling-tcp-connection-lost-on-mysql-c-connector